# Opening QGIS Python console from Linux command prompt

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I am trying to run on a remote Linux cluster a PyQGIS python script I wrote, after managing to run my script locally, but I am having trouble setting up things in the Linux server.

To run the script locally, I followed the steps indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622661/import-qgis-modules-into-python-anaconda/67447061#67447061 which comprise running

```
import sys
sys.path
```

on the Python console of QGIS GUI. However, I cannot open the QGIS GUI in the Linux cluster. T

Is there any way I could open the QGIS Python console directly from the Linux command prompt?

I already installed QGIS in a conda environment on the Linux cluster (it is QGIS version 3.18.3).

Answer (score 3):

This may help.  [See this link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/standalone) for running QGIS processing scripts from a command line without having to open a QGIS GUI.

Here I place a script called start.py in my home directory in Ubuntu.
The contents of start.py are

```
print('QGIS Python ran this')
```

Then, from a terminal I type:

```
$qgis_process run start.py
```

This returns *QGIS Python ran this* in the terminal.  It also returned text stating that start.py is not a valid Processing script but I suspect you will not get that message if your script is valid.

Comment: qgis_process run start.py did not work with message:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:10.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

After some research I ran export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen. And then qgis_process throws error: Problem with SAGA installation: SAGA was not found or is not correctly installed
Algorithm start.py not found!
Any advice? I don't have admin rights to cluster

Comment: No, other that search GIS SE for help on settings to get SAGA working.  That was straight forward on a Linux laptop but I don't know about the server...Or ignore the return if you don't need SAGA.  Best to start a new question on the topic.  Conversations in the comments are frowned upon by the administrators.